# Logs from Web3.js application and Smart Contract

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, truffle, blockchain

I would like to know where are the logs printed when I use "console.log(x)" in a web3 app. I am using Geth and Truffle to deploy smart contracts.

For example, from pet-shop tutorial, if I wanna see a log with the petId when a pet is adopted, where is it printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's the normal javascript, then it will be output on the console of the browser